# Display a list of names based on checked boxes in other page - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, checkbox, data-binding

I have a view with a lot of labels and checkboxes, it is basically a list of questions for the user and if the user answers yes, they check the checkbox, otherwise they don't. I have another view that is related to this first view in which it should get and display which check boxes were checked. For example:

```
<Label Text="You have fever?" />
<CheckBox x:Name="fever" />

<Label Text="You have a running nose?" />
<CheckBox x:Name="running_nose" />

<Label Text="You are feeling dizzy?" />
<CheckBox x:Name="dizzy" />
```

And on the other page I want to display the values that were checked in a entry field. Let's say the user checked fever and dizzy. On the other page it would display something like this:

```
"You marked *fever*, *dizzy*. Is that right?"
```

How can I do this? I know I can use data binding. But not sure how to. In my actual app, I have around 10 fields of those and I need to display on the other page the was that were marked. I was also thinking in instead of displaying an entry with these values, I would created a card for each one of the checked boxes (my app is much more complex, the symptoms are just an example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to model your data

create a class that is something like this

```
public class Symptom
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Prompt { get; set; }
  public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

then create a list with data

```
List<Symptom> symptoms = new List<Symptom>();

symptoms.Add(new Sympton { Name = "fever", Prompt = "You have fever?" });
// repeat for others
```

then you can display this data in a ListView or CollectionView

```
<ListView x:Name="lstSymptoms">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Prompt}" />
                <Checkbox Selected="{Binding Selected" />
            <StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView>
```

then in the code behind, assign your model to the list

```
lstSymptoms.ItemSource = symptoms;
```

when the user is done selecting, you can use LINQ to create a list of just the selected symptoms, and pass that to the next page

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Isn't there a way to automatically bind the data to the other page? My first idea was to create a an event handler that would be triggered whenever a check is changed, this method would get the ClassID of the sender and add as string to a List<Strings> and then I would pass that List to the other page by I wanted to do more dynamically (with data binding). Aren't these solutions similar?

Comment: Just passing strings around isn’t a very good way to model your data.  You could certainly use binding on the 2nd page too

Comment: Fair enough. Alright, I will try it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I have just one more question. I'm implementing your solution (and it works fine) but now I need to pass the list to the other page, however both pages are tabbed pages from the same parent. Any tips on how to pass the list from one to another?

Comment: Do you mean that both pages are children of the same TabbedPage?